# How can I return the index of the second word in a string that can have multiple white spaces followed by one word followed by multiple white spaces?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, substring

```
String str ="  vol   ABCD C  XYZ";
```

I want to return the index of "A"

Note: There are multiple white spaces before all words including the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the index of A in your original example (`String str =" vol ABCD C XYZ";`):

```
int indexOfABCD = str.IndexOf(str.Trim()[str.Trim().IndexOf(' ')+1]);
```

If you have something like `String str = " vol    ABCD    C   XYZ";` where there are multiple spaces:

```
        string secondword = str.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
        int indexOfAinABCD = str.IndexOf(secondword.First());
```

If you want to get the indices of all the letters in the second word:

```
        IEnumerable<int> fullindex =  Enumerable.Range(indexOfAinABCD, secondword.Length);
```

EDIT:

This will fail if you have A anywhere else in the first word. You should get an exact match through Regex:

```
int indexOfAinABCD = Regex.Match(str, string.Format(@"\W{0}\W",secondword)).Index+1;
IEnumerable<int> fullindex =  Enumerable.Range(indexOfAinABCD, secondword.Length);
```

So something like `String str = " vABCDol    ABCD    C    XYZ";` won't be an issue

Comment: Note that this will fail if the first letter of the second word also appears somewhere in the first word.